# lack of speedup and erroneous results with OpenMP and Cython

Tags: python, c, multithreading, openmp, cython

I'm trying to speed up a simple piece of code written in Cython with OpenMP. It's a double loop that for each position in the input array adds a quantity at each reference point. Here's the main part of the code:

```
cimport cython  
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport openmp
DTYPE = np.double
ctypedef np.double_t DTYPE_t

cdef extern from "math.h" nogil :
  DTYPE_t sqrt(DTYPE_t)


@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def summation(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] pos, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=1] weights, 
              np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] points, int num_threads = 0):

    from cython.parallel cimport prange, parallel, threadid

    if num_threads <= 0 : 
        num_threads = openmp.omp_get_num_procs()

    if num_threads > openmp.omp_get_num_procs() : 
        num_threads = openmp.omp_get_num_procs()

    openmp.omp_set_num_threads(num_threads)

    cdef unsigned int nips = len(points)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] sum_array = np.zeros(nips, dtype = np.float64)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] sum_array3d = np.zeros((nips,3), dtype = np.float64)

    cdef unsigned int n = len(weights)

    cdef unsigned int pi, i, id
    cdef double dx, dy, dz, dr, weight_i, xi,yi,zi

    print 'num_threads = ', openmp.omp_get_num_threads()

    for i in prange(n,nogil=True,schedule='static'):
        weight_i = weights[i]
        xi = pos[i,0]
        yi = pos[i,1]
        zi = pos[i,2]
        for pi in range(nips) :
            dx = points[pi,0] - xi
            dy = points[pi,1] - yi
            dz = points[pi,2] - zi
            dr = 1.0/sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz)
            sum_array[pi] += weight_i * dr
            sum_array3d[pi,0] += weight_i * dx
            sum_array3d[pi,1] += weight_i * dy
            sum_array3d[pi,2] += weight_i * dz


    return sum_array, sum_array3d
```

I've put it into a gist with the associated test and setup files (https://gist.github.com/rokroskar/6ed1bfc1a5f8f9c183a6)

Two issues arise:

First, in the current configuration I'm not able to get any speedup. The code runs on multiple cores, but the timings show no advantage.

Second, the results are different depending on the number of cores indicating that there's a 
race condition. Aren't the in-place sums supposed to end up being reductions? Or is something funny happening since it's a nested for loop? I figured everything inside the `prange` is executed in each thread individually.

Both of these go away if I reverse the order of the loops -- but because my outer loop the way it's structured now is where all the data reading gets done, if I reverse them the arrays are traversed num_thread times which is wasteful. I've also tried putting the whole nested loop inside a `with parallel():` block and use thread-local buffers explicitly but wasn't able to get it to work.

Clearly I'm missing something basic about how OpenMP is supposed to work (though maybe this is particular to Cython?) so I would be grateful for tips!

Comment: Maybe retagging with `c` and `c++` will help you get more views and possibly some answers?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried switching the two loops so you don't have multiple threads reading and writing from the same locations? I'm pretty sure that these loops are not automatically promoted into an OpenMP reduction and increments such as "sum_array3d[pi,0] += weight_i * dx" are not atomic.

Also, since the computation is relatively simple, Cython might be overkill and you might get away with using either [Parakeet](http://www.parakeetpython.com) or [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) instead.

Parakeet will, by default, use OpenMP to execute comprehensions in parallel. You would have to rewrite your code to look something like:

```
@parakeet.jit
def summation(pos, weights, points):
  n_points = len(points)
  n_weights = len(weights)
  sum_array3d = np.zeros((n_points,3))
  def compute(i):
    pxi = points[i, 0]
    pyi = points[i, 1]
    pzi = points[i, 2]
    total = 0.0
    for j in xrange(n_weights):
      weight_j = weights[j]
      xj = pos[j,0]
      yj = pos[j,1]
      zj = pos[j,2]
      dx = pxi - pos[j, 0]
      dy = pyi - pos[j, 1]
      dz = pzi - pos[j, 2]
      dr = 1.0/np.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz)
      total += weight_j * dr
      sum_array3d[i,0] += weight_j * dx
      sum_array3d[i,1] += weight_j * dy
      sum_array3d[i,2] += weight_j * dz
    return total 
  sum_array = np.array([compute(i) for i in xrange(n_points)])
  return sum_array, sum_array3d
```

As for Numba, I'm not sure if the [prange](http://docs.continuum.io/numbapro/prange.html) construct has made it into the free version yet.

edit: *Forehead slap*, sorry I missed the part of your question where you considered switching the loops.

Comment: hi @alex-rubinsteyn, thanks for your answer -- I want to use cython as it is currently the most portable and widely used. As I said in my question, yes, if I reverse the two loops everything is fine, but then I have to traverse the full data array once for each point, which seems like a waste. I don't understand why in that case the reduction works fine and not in the order I have it the above code.

Comment: Hey Rok, sorry I missed that part of your question. The problem boils down to destructive updates like "sum_array3d[pi,0] += weight_i * dx". Two threads can both have the same value of pi at the same time. They both read sum_array3d[0,0]. Then each locally increments that value, and they both write back their local result. Whichever thread goes second overwrites the result of the first, hence your race condition. In ordinary C/C++ code I think you could fix the correctness with "#pragma omp atomic" or locking but I'm not sure how to do this in Cython and anyhow it would kill your performance.

Comment: hi alex, yes ordinarily this would be a race condition, except that in side the cython prange statement it's supposed to turn in-place operators into a reduction. E.g. from the [cython documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html): "Thread-locality and reductions are automatically inferred for variables. If you use an inplace operator on a variable, it becomes a reduction."

Comment: I think the key word there is "variable". This might be a corner of OpenMP spec I'm unfamiliar with, but I believe that the variables given to an "#omp parallel reduction" pragma must be simple local names, not a position in an array. Cython probably only looks for patterns of the form "reduction_var += some_val" and silently ignores "reduction_array[idx] += some_val".

Comment: Yep, I just tried using an array element as the reduction variable and OpenMP barfs:

"""
test.c:8:42: error: expected ')' before '[' token
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum[0])
                                          ^
test.c:8:36: error: 'sum' has invalid type for 'reduction'
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum[0])
"""

I doubt Cython is going to be significantly more clever here than their compile target.

Comment: ahaaaaa I see. Thanks for clarifying this point! I guess you need to specify that it's an atomic operation -- doesn't seem like that's possible with cython unfortunately.